# Disabling certain JBoss ports

Tags: security, jboss, port

We are trying to configure JBoss 5.1.0 to be as lightweight and as secure as possible. One of the parts of this process is to identify and close any ports we do not need.

Three ports that we have outstanding but don't believe we need are:

- 4457 - bisocket
- 4712 - JBossTS Recovery Manager
- 4713 - JBossTS Transaction Status Manager

We don't think we need any of these features (but could be wrong).

Bisocket seems to be a way for JMS clients behind a firewall to communicate with JBoss. We hardly use JMS now and when we do, it is very unlikely that we will need this firewall traversing ability.

I am less sure about whether we need the two JBossTS ports - I am guessing these are used in a clustered environment - we aren't clustered.

So my question is, how do we disable these ports (and associated processes where possible), or if we need these ports, why do we need to keep them open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to disable the above ports:

- bisocket - change remoting-bisocket-service.xml so that the `<invoker transport="bisocket">` line uses local
- JBossTS Recovery Manager - change jbossts-properties.xml so that the `<property name="com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.transactionStatusManagerEnable" value="YES"/>` reads NO
- JBossTS Recovery Manager - change jbossts-properties.xml so that the `<property name="com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.recoveryListener" value="YES"/>` reads NO